# Calling Stored Procedure with Parameters in Azure Function gives error

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure, azure-functions

I'm trying to write an Azure Function in C# that calls an Azure SQL stored procedure with a parameter but it gives an error...

> Exception while executing function: Functions.EventHubRaw. mscorlib: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Procedure or function 'FaultDetails' expects parameter '@FaultID', which was not supplied.

What am I missing?

It's a very simple stored procedure with just a single integer parameter. I've tried adding the parameter to the command in all kinds of different ways but it always produces the same error.

Here's the code segment from the Azure Function...

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@FaultID", SqlDbType.Int);
cmd.Parameters["@FaultID"].Value = faultID;
// cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FaultID", faultID);
// cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FaultID", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = faultID;
var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

And here is the stored procedure...

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[FaultDetails]
(
    @FaultID int
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

SELECT        Fault.FaultID, Fault.ErrCode, Fault.StatusID, Status.DeviceID, Status.Counter, Status.LMU34Telegram, Status.EventProcessedUtcTime, Status.GenTime, Device.Description, Device.ModelNumber, Device.SerialNumber, 
                         Device.Latitude, Device.Longitude, Agent.Name, Agent.Email, Agent.Telephone
FROM            Fault INNER JOIN
                         Status ON Fault.StatusID = Status.StatusID INNER JOIN
                         Device ON Status.DeviceID = Device.DeviceID INNER JOIN
                         Agent ON Device.AgentID = Agent.AgentID
WHERE        (Fault.FaultID = @FaultID)

END
```

Pretty simple stuff, no?

Comment: What's in the c#'s `faultID` variable?

Comment: Oh no! <blush> My faultID variable was null for all paths. Sorry guys, my bad. It now works just fine. Thank you!

Comment: To be fair... that's a very misleading error and there's nothing in your proc saying that `@FaultID` can't be NULL

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the Parameter direction...

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FaultID", SqlDbType.Int)
                {
                    Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
                    Value = faultID
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

We don't know what's your `faultID` variable. But the `faultId` must a Int data type.
Azure provides our a sample about `command.Parameters.Add()` method:

```
public void AddSqlParameter(SqlCommand command) 
{
    SqlParameter param = command.Parameters.Add(
        "@Description", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
    param.Size = 16;
    param.Value = "Beverages";
}
```

For more details, you can see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlParameterCollection_Add_System_String_System_Data_SqlDbType_).

I think maybe you can try to change your code like this and try again:

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(@FaultID", SqlDbType.Int));  
cmd.Parameters["@FaultID"].Value = 1;
var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Hope this can helps you.